# How to ignore double-clicks and detect single-clicks in C with GTK4 (< 4.10)?

Tags: c, events, event-handling, gtk, gesture

In Gtk4 (4.6) with C-language on Ubuntu 22.04, I am trying to detect single-clicks while ignoring double-clicks. However, when a double-click occurs, the first of the two very close clicks is treated as a single-click. I consulted the Gtk4 documentation, but I did not understand how to solve this problem in a simple way.

Here is what I tried:

```
GtkGesture *controller;
controller = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
gtk_gesture_single_set_button (GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE (controller), 0);
gtk_gesture_single_set_exclusive (GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE (controller), TRUE);
gtk_event_controller_set_propagation_phase (GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (controller), GTK_PHASE_CAPTURE);
g_signal_connect_after (controller, "released", G_CALLBACK (on_click), myWidget);
gtk_widget_add_controller (GTK_WIDGET (myWidget), GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (controller));
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas for the time spent making these improvements.

Answer (score 0):

The callback for `GtkGestureClick`'s ["released"](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/signal.GestureClick.released.html) signal has a `n_press` argument which allows you to check for the number of consecutive clicks. In other words, if `n_press` is set to 2, you're dealing with a double click.

So for example, your `on_click` function could look like the following:

```c
static void
on_click (GtkGestureClick *controller,
          int n_press,
          double x,
          double y,
          void *user_data)
{
    if (n_press == 2) { // Maybe you would check (n_press > 1) here
        g_debug ("Detected double click, ignoring");
        return;
    }

    // Do whatever logic you wanted to do here for single clicks
}
```

Comment: With this approach, each double-click causes 2 calls of the the callback.
First call of the call back : just after the first click and just before the second click (ie. between the 2 clicks of the double-click), and the callback is misled because GTK tells (n_press==1) it is a single-click (it's a "false" single-click: it's only the first click of a double-click sequence).
Second call of the callback : just after the second click. And at that time the callback is informed by GTK (n_press==2) of a double click. But it's too late: the previous callback call processed the "false" single click.

Comment: I see. The only thing I can think of then is to use `g_timeout_add()` with a timeout of [GtkSettings::gtk-double-click-time](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/property.Settings.gtk-double-click-time.html) when `n_press == 1`. If you didn't get a double-click before that callback, you'll have a single click